# FragmentPagerAdapter update title dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter, which has 3 Fragments. Now, I have **a number of items as part of the title** of the fragment:

[image]

So user can add or remove those items, and title should update accordingly. However, this title seems static.

How can one recall this method to update FragmentPagerAdapter's titles?

```
@Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return items + " (" + notFoundItems + ")";
            case 1: return found;
            case 2: return review;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

I found a couple of similar questions on SO, but I need to update **title**, not only the fragment itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I solved it by simply re-setting the pager.

```
private OrdersTabsAdapter tabsAdapter;
@InjectView(R.id.tabs_orders) SlidingTabLayout ordersTabs;
@InjectView(R.id.pager) ViewPager pager;

public void update() {
  tabsAdapter.updateFragments(productId, status);
  ordersTabs.setViewPager(pager); //this helped with the titles
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling 'setViewPager()' you're better off calling 'setTabsFromPagerAdapter(PagerAdapter adapter)'. This has the exact same effect ('setViewPager()' calls this method internally) and you skip some extra work since 'setViewPager()' also sets up some listeners. Basically all it does it remove and re-add all tabs. There are some private 'update' methods but even when called with Reflection, they do not seem to have any effect on the titles.

Comment: `mTabs.setViewPager(pager);` would just DO it!

Comment: Hi I managed to get the `update()` method called in the adapter, but can you show me how you change the title in `getPageTitle`? Mine doesn't seem to get called even if `getCount` returns some value.

Answer (score 9):

As one of the comments beneath it suggests, the accepted answer looks a bit overkill to me.

Based on [Frank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31653614/1617737), this is what I have done:

```
public void myUpdatePageTitle(int pagePosition, int numItems) {
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(pagePosition);
    if (tab != null) {
        tab.setText(myCalcTabTitle(pagePosition, numItems));
    }
}

private String myCalcTabTitle(int pagePosition, int numItems) {
    //TODO - For this page, return whatever title string you like, including the numItems value. (The best way to do this is using a string resource that accepts a decimal parameter.)
}
```

Comment: I've been reviewing many answers and to me this is probably the best in terms of performance. Of course calling notifyDataSetChanged() would work but that's really bad if in each of your fragments you are doing heavy operations or connecting to Internet.

Answer (score 5):

Okay. So you can have a method in `FragmentPagerAdapter` that will update the count for `notFoundItems`, `foundItems`, `itemsForReview`. After you update them, call the `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
 @Override
 public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return items + " (" + notFoundItems + ")";
            case 1: return found + " (" + foundItems + ")";
            case 2: return review + " (" + itemsForReview + ")";
        }
        return "";
 }
```

Also, add this to the your implementation of `FragmentPagerAdapter` class. So whenever you have a new data count and want to update the title, call this method.

```
 public void updateTitleData(int notFoundItems, int foundItems, int itemsForReview) {
      this.notFoundItems = notFoundItems;
      this.foundItems = foundItems;
      this.itemsForReview = itemsForReview;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work. I tried notifyDataSetChanged(); before, it doesn't update titles.

Comment: @Roman Did u look at `viewpagerindicator`. That library has `TitlePageIndicator`. Are you using this?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() works inside a custom FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 5):

you have 3 fragments so you will use 3 tabs(first tab hav index 0,second 1,third 2).
get your tab using index and set her text as title.
May this help you bro

Example:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.getTabAt(index).setText("");
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think reset ViewPager and notifyDataSetChange is a good idea. Because it will cause the view in ViewPager to recreate. It's unnecessary.

And i found another way to solve the problem.

```
    List<OrderListResult.TradeStatusVOsEntity> tradeStatusVOs = updateTitleEvent.getTradeStatusVOs();
    for (int i = 0; i < tradeStatusVOs.size(); i++) {
        OrderListResult.TradeStatusVOsEntity tradeStatusVOsEntity = tradeStatusVOs.get(i);
        int num = tradeStatusVOsEntity.getNum();
        String text = mAdapter.getPageTitle(i).toString();
        if (num > 0) {
            text = text + "(" + num + ")";
        }
        mButterTabs.getTabAt(i).setText(text);
    }

    mButterTabs.setTabTextColors(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
```

First, you need to use `getTabAt` method of `TabLayout` to change the model of tab. Then call `setTabTextColors` to update view. Because from the source code of TabLayout, `setTabTextColors` will update all tabs one by one.

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in your re setting your pager each time.
You've already got getPageTitle() overridden and you are just missing to track when your pages are changed and when is the time to update the title.
So you can easily do this:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // your tite is: mAdapter.getPageTitle(position));
        // TODO: update title
    }
});
```

Also you will have to set initial title in onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

`TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` will be triggered when re-setup with the `ViewPager`, so I recommend update the title by self.

```
viewPager.adapter?.apply {
    for (p in 0..count) {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(p)?.text = getPageTitle(p) ?: break
    }
}
```